# Python cv2 read raw video like bayer bggr8?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, raw-input

I try to read raw video pixel format as bayer bggr8 in Python cv2.
And grab frame by frame.
What are the possible approaches? 
Thanks in advance:)
I’m scratching my head for hours now.

Comment: Please elaborate. Have you got a file of Bayer bggr8 data? Or have you got a divide that is streaming Bayer bggr8 data? How do you receive the data - Ethernet? AVFoundation? V4L2? What OS are you using? What is the device?

Comment: Sorry for confusing descriptions. I’m on windows64. The data is on local disk. My plan is using for cv2.VideoCapture(), but got stuck there:(

Comment: Is your aim to work on demosaicing algorithms or are you happy to let some other software demosaic for you because your goal is some other processing after the demosaicing?

Comment: It’s just a demo like program. World like open source way:)

Comment: Why not convert your Bayer BGGR8 to something OpenCV can read with `ffmpeg`using something like `ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_bggr8 -video_size 1024x768 -i YourFile.yuv -c:v libx264 output.avi`

Comment: I can do that, but later I still would grab those bayer format frames from a usb camera.  Right now I looking at gstreamer pipeline, which is enabled starting cv 3.1.